# Does it make sense to compare which one of two points to two entries of an array is bigger?

Tags: c

In C, I have an array `int A[20]`. I have two pointers `int *pi` and `int *pj` pointing to two  entries `A[i]` and `A[j]`  respectively. I don't know `i` and `j`. I would like to know if `i > j` or `j<i` or `i==j`.

My thought is to do that by comparing `pi` and `pj`based on that `pi = A + i` and `pj=A+j`. I wonder if it is correct that `i > j` if and only if `pi>pj`, and `i == j` if and only if `pi==pj`? Thanks!

Comment: yes of course, I would expect you to know that.

Comment: yes valid, because this is how compiler use `A[i]` to  `*(A + i)`, so array get allocation  like this.

Comment: Pointer gymnastics are pretty common in C, just be aware of the size of the type you're pointing to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `<` and `>` operators on pointers are defined to work in exactly that way.

And for pointers that don't point into the same object or just past the end of it, the behavior of `<` and `>` is undefined. `==` and `!=` are well defined, though.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.8, paragraph 5:

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative
>   locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two
>   pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point
>   one past the last element of the same array object, they compare
>   equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate
>   object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater
>   than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and
>   pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare
>   greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower
>   subscript values.  All pointers to members of the same union object
>   compare equal. If the expression **`P`** points to an element of an
>   array object and the expression **`Q`** points to the last element of
>   the same array object, the pointer expression **`Q+1`** compares
>   greater than
>   **`P`**. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Array allocation in "increasing memory address" is also defined (I mean in C standards)? I think yes because compilers treat `A[i]` as `*(A + i)`..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, it is.

Comment: "== and <= are well defined, though" -- I think you mean "!="

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a valid comparison. If

```
pi = &A[i] = A + i
```

and

```
pj = &A[j] = A + j
```

then it is true that

```
(pi < pj) == (i < j)
```

Comment: I think you wanted to use equivalence rather than equality in your last statement.

Comment: Equivalence follows from equality in this case by reversing the roles of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, what distinction are you making?

Comment: @Felipe We're talking specifically about the C programming language here, where the expression `x < y` has both a logical meaning and a numerical value.

Comment: @JeremyWest Fair enough, I get your point. Nevermind, I was just nitpicking :P But yeah, in C context it makes sense.

Comment: "what distinction are you making?" -- in-language vs. metalanguage. But the in-language expression is fine here.